# Am I right about this dropped "which"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I think a "which" has been dropped in the following paragraph that has led to misunderstanding. Am I right? I have added and made bold where I think it is missing.

> There are dangers in drawing too many inferences from animal behaviour models and applying them to humans but there is something obviously recognisable in this ‘Machiavellian behaviour’, as it has been described by ethologists (animal behaviourists), even while they are wary of the dangers of using human behaviour models to apply to animals. The notion that communities are always ruled by competing Alpha males and that females play a subordinate role **[, which]** does not feel acceptable in a post-Marxist, postfeminist society.

I mean "The notion that communities are always ruled by competing Alpha males and that females play a subordinate role" should be, according to the original text, "the thing that is obviously recognisable in this Machiavellian behaviour". Am I right about it?

Comment: No. The sentence is fine without the added *which*. The entire first part before *does not feel* functions as the subject, for which *does not feel acceptable* is the predicate.

Comment: Parse it as *The notion [that ... role] does not feel acceptable*.

Comment: When you add your "improvement" the sentence doesn't even parse -- there is no subject/verb.

Answer (score 1):

So that this question receives an answer rather than just comments, I'll summarise what has been said so far.

> The notion that communities are always ruled by competing Alpha males
>   and that females play a subordinate role does not feel acceptable in a
>   post-Marxist, postfeminist society.

That sentence is correct. See the following shortened version.

**The notion does not feel acceptable in a post-Marxist, postfeminist society.**

Expanding again:

**The notion** *that communities are always ruled by competing Alpha males and that females play a subordinate role* **does not feel acceptable in a post-Marxist, postfeminist society.**

Comment: So, what is the thing that "is obviously recognisable in this Machiavellian behaviour"? I thought the sentence "The notion that communities..." is this thing, and it was why I thought a "while" might have been dropped in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the thing that "is obviously recognisable in this 'Machiavellian behaviour'"? I thought the sentence "The notion that communities..." is this thing, and it was why I thought a "which" might have been dropped in this sentence.

"This 'Machiavellian behaviour' refers to something implied in the [preceding passage](https://books.google.com/books?id=xCkBAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=animal%20behaviourists%20%22machiavellian%20behaviour%22&source=bl&ots=E_d3LsKaYx&sig=wq44deH15q6RgO2_Xdwz04f_vVk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMI2Jyqx_zOxwIVS5QNCh1cagGV#v=onepage&q&f=false), a description of intrigue, deception, coup de'états and plot twists involving a colony of chimpanzees, that reminded the author of the original story of Machiavelli.